# Let $f$ be the ring automorphism of $\mathbf{C}$. Prove $f(1) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Let $f$ be the ring automorphism of $\mathbf{C}$. Prove $f(1) = 1$.

I am a little stuck on this proof. I know by definition of ring isomorphism that the unity gets mapped to the unity, but that's not a proof that just me stating a property of ring homomorphisms.

Here is my attempt at a proof looking for feedback as proof writing is a struggle for me:

Suppose we have ring R and ring S where $f(x_R) \rightarrow x_S$, with R having unity 1.
and $f$ is onto.
Since $f$ is onto we always have $x \in R$ that maps to a element in $S$.
Note that then $f(x)\times f(1) = f(x \times 1)= f(x)$
That is $f(1)$ is the unity of $S$

Since the problem states that "$f$ be the ring automorphism of $\mathbf{C}$",meaning $f$ maps $\mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$ and in our example $R, S =\mathbf{C}$.
Then this implies 1 is the unity of $S$.
Therefore $f(1)=1$

Comment: Looks good! With practice you'll also get a better handle on what needs to be stated, but it's better to overexplain than under at first.

Comment: What you've written looks fine to me.  First you proved that for any ring with $1$ and any automorphism of that ring, it must be the case that $f(1)=1$.  You then noted that the problem you're presented with is a special case of that more general fact.

Comment: Alternatively, $1^2=1$ implies $f(1)^2=f(1)$ and so $f(1)=1$ or $f(1)=0$. But it can't be $f(1)=0$ because $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is injective.