# Let $f$ be the ring automorphism of $\mathbf{C}$. Prove $f(-1) = -1$. Verificaiton?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $f$ be the ring automorphism of $\mathbf{C}$. Prove $f(-1) = -1$.

Do I need to show that $f(x)=x$ before I do my final step? Also I was looking further in the book I am studying and they later ask to prove $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=-x$ for the same automorphism... This implies my proof cannot be correct?  Proof as follow:

To prove $f(-x) = -x$, which is to say $f$ preserves negation, we can start off with $x+ -x = 0$.
Note that a property of an isomorphism is $f(a)+f(a)= a+a$
then we can see $f(x)+ f(-x) =0$ 
minus $f(x)$ from each side to get $ f(-x) =-f(x)$
Thus if $x=1$ then$ f(-1) =-f(1)= -1$

Comment: Ready for countably many questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4333101/let-f-be-the-ring-automorphism-of-mathbfc-prove-f1-1

Comment: @reuns I wasn't sure if I should ask them in one question or separately. I have two other similar questions like this from Pinter's textbook. Should I wrap them all in one thread? They sort of build off themselves.

Comment: I see you already know $f(1) = 1$ in a ring with unit.  Do you also know $f(0) = 0$?  Then $f(0-1) = \dots$.

Comment: @EricTowers Oh. duh. Thank you.

Comment: Why not look at $f(1-1)$? What is "Let f be the ring automorphism of C"?